# How can I set a command block to /say something when a player stands on a certain set of coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Sorry for the simple question, but I can't find this anywhere after quite a few searches. I have a statue on my server and I would like it if text came up as a caption for any player approaching it on a single-block pedestal in front of it. Right now I have `/execute if entity @a[x=-920,y=61,z=446] run say test`, but that spams the message over and over again no matter where the player is. The command block is set to 'repeating', 'unconditional', and 'always active'. Setting it to 'conditional' doesn't allow it to work at all. Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Thank you!

EDIT: I *think* that my question is different than the ones testing to see if a mob is at a certain location because I am specifically asking for advice on how to execute the 'say' command when the circumstances are met. That being said, the answers in the other thread helped a lot, so it marking my thread as a duplicate may be the best option.

Comment: @Fabian That suggested duplicate seems to only address half of the question, though, right?

Comment: @Joachim Which half? The question is about executing a command when a player is at certain coordinates.

Comment: @FabianRöling The naming half, that the OP just updated his question on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a position in a target selector, you need to define the delta values as well. That would look like this in your case:

```
/execute if entity @a[x=-920,y=61,z=446,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0] run say test
```

Comment: I recommend you check out the `/title` command for your situation, you can find more information about it here: https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/title_command.php